# Protractor tests results monitoring?

Tags: testing, integration-testing, monitoring, protractor

I was wondering if there is a service where I could send data and then group that data however I want and later display it in charts or similar?

What I want to do is - start protractor e2e tests and let them run forever. Since some of the tests randomly fail I can not rely on them if they were included in main build. What I'm going to do is run tests in each supported browser over and over again and then capture which tests failed in which browser, if they passed - reset failure counter and so on.. That way I can monitor how my system is doing without wasting my time waiting for build to run successfully.

My data could look something like that:

```
{
  testName: 'Path to test + name',
  status: 'failed/passed',
  browser: 'firefox/chrome/safari/opera...'
}
```

Now when test fails in (let's say) chrome over and over again I will see that it's error counter is constantly increasing, that means something is either wrong with system or I need to fix test in chrome.

Does anyone know service that could consume my data and display aggregated info?